# vba freeze panes without sheet activating

Tags: excel, vba, select, freeze, pane

Is it possible to freeze top row without activating/selecting the cells/sheets?
I just want to specify the Workbook, Sheet and what to freeze on it.

```
Sheets(1).Activate
With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Comment: Use this: `With Sheets(1).Parent.Parent.Windows(Sheets(1).Parent.Name)` instead of `With ActiveWindow`

Comment: @AcsErno this code works, but freeze panes applies only to the active sheet, even I changed sheet Index.  However I need: when the active sheet is Sheet2, apply freeze top row on Sheet1, without activating Sheet1.

Comment: The code looks like this:
`
`With Sheets(1).Parent.Parent.Windows(Sheets(1).Parent.Name)`
 `.SplitColumn = 0`
 `.SplitRow = 1`
 `.FreezePanes = True`
`End With`
`

Comment: `Sheets(1)` directly refers to `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)` that is literally the 1st sheet in the active workbook. You can use object variables instead of `Sheets(1)` to make sheet reference more flexible. Browse the documentation for more.

Comment: Even I use code 
`With Sheets(1).Parent.Parent.Windows(Sheets(1).Parent.Name) .SplitColumn = 0 .SplitRow = 1 .FreezePanes = True End With`
  freeze panes applies for active sheet, it can be not only Sheet1, also Sheet2, Sheet3 etc. So, looks like in this code frreze panes applies for active sheet of active workbook, independently what is written in code Sheet(i), the main thing is that such a Sheet(i) would exist.  However I need: when the active sheet is Sheet2, apply freeze top row on Sheet1, without activating Sheet1.

Comment: The trick I showed you helps avoiding reference on `ActiveWindow`. Unfortunately `.FreezePanes` is a property of a `Window` object so you can't really avoid operating with windows. In addition, there no support on specifing the target cell, so all you can do is selecting/activating all affected sheets one by one, select/activate the target cell, and issue the `.FreezePanes = True` command.

Comment: At which moment do you want to freeze in `Sheet1`? I mean, what is happening in `Sheet2`? You can't avoid activating, but you can automate it. Maybe share some lines of code before and after the lines when you need to freeze.

Comment: thanks all for helping. As I repeat all what I need is: when the active sheet is Sheet2, apply freeze top row on Sheet1, without activating Sheet1. As I understand this is rather impossible as freeze panes method works only with activewindow.

Answer (score 1):

### Freeze Window 'Without Activating'

- Of course, it's not possible but here is the automation I mentioned in the comments.
- This might help, although I cannot see the purpose of it.
- In the `ThisWorkbook` module paste the following code.
- Adjust the sheet names, codenames, or indexes.

```vb
Option Explicit


Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Then Freeze1
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2" Then Freeze1
End Sub


Private Sub Freeze1()
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Me.Sheets(1).Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With
    Me.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    
SafeExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```